# UseEffect infinite loop with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

Hi i'm trying to build a simple chat, but I encountered some issues when reading the messages.

```
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const messagesArray = [];
  const messagesRef = firestore().collection('messages');

useEffect(() => {
    id
      ? messagesRef
          .where('idRequest', '==', id)
          .orderBy('createdAt')
          .limit(25)
          .get()
          .then((response) => {
            response.forEach((doc) => {
              messagesArray.push(doc.data());
            });
            setMessages(messagesArray);
            console.log('Changes: ', messages);
          })
      : console.log('No ID provided.');
  }, [messages]);
```

If I run it with the dependency '`messages`', It works, but the app gets very slow, so I placed a console.log to check the flow of the `useEffect`, and I figured it was on an infinite loop, looking for changes over and over. I assume this happens because whenever the useEffect runs, It 're sets' the `messages` array, so that causes it to run again.
I can solve the loop issue by removing '`messages`' from the dependency array, but the problem is it won't render again when a new message is sent or received. So I'm not sure what I should do.

PS: The chat depends on the actual user ID, the condition at the start is to assure an ID is received, otherwhise it shouldn't query the firestore db.

Comment: Hi. can we not check if the message retrieved is already in the messagesArray before pushing it and calling setMessages? We can't remove messages from the dependency but we can check if the message retrieved is already there or not

Comment: I'm not sure how I could make that happen, I'm kind of new to programming. Do you mean like, somehow getting the values of messagesArray, and comparing it to the new message on the state? I don't know how I could be able to do so

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and the following seem to work. Like @Thor0o0 said, you would need a conditional statement to check if you already captured the message in your state.

I would use `id` as a dependency and not `messages`.

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const messagesRef = firestore().collection('messages');

useEffect(() => {
  if(!id) return console.log('No ID provided.');
  const messagesArray = messages;

  messagesRef
    .where('idRequest', '==', id)
    .orderBy('createdAt')
    .limit(25)
    .get()
    .then((response) => {
      response.forEach((doc) => {
       const foundMsgIndex = messagesArray.findIndex(msg=>msg.id===doc.id)
       if(foundMsgIndex < 0){ 
           messagesArray.push({...doc.data(), id:doc.id});
       }
      });
      setMessages(messagesArray);
      console.log('Changes: ', messages);
      }) 
  }, [id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `SetMessages()` inside the `UseEffect`, which changes `messages`, which triggers your useEffect.

Your linter should have caught this.

Comment: The linter suggested me to add: id, messages and messagesArray to the dependencies. I tried that, but It behaved the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you need to keep the messages array as a dependency of useEffect, what you can do is keep a copy of the messages array in a ref and compare it to the messages variable in your useEffect callback.

```js
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const messagesArray = [];
const messagesRef = firestore().collection("messages");

const lastMessages = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // Only do something if the messages variable was reassigned outside of the useEffect
  if (messages !== lastMessages.current) {
    id
      ? messagesRef
          .where("idRequest", "==", id)
          .orderBy("createdAt")
          .limit(25)
          .get()
          .then((response) => {
            response.forEach((doc) => {
              messagesArray.push(doc.data());
            });

            // Update the value of the ref
            lastMessages.current = messagesArray;

            setMessages(messagesArray);

            console.log("Changes: ", messages);
          })
      : console.log("No ID provided.");
  }
}, [messages]);
```

This works because the value of a ref is preserved even when the component re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below.

```
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const messagesArray = [];
  const messagesRef = firestore().collection('messages');

useEffect(() => {
    id
      ? messagesRef
          .where('idRequest', '==', id)
          .orderBy('createdAt')
          .limit(25)
          .get()
          .then((response) => {
            response.forEach((doc) => {
              //check here if the message is already in the messages array 
              //before pushing it and calling setMessages. Use findIndex or 
              //filter method to do so.

                //something like this
               const messageExists = messages.findIndex(doc.data());
               if (!messageExists){
              messagesArray.push(doc.data());
              setMessages(messagesArray);
            });
          })
      : console.log('No ID provided.');
  }, [messages]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only time you use `messages` in your `useEffect` is for `console.log('Changes: ', messages)` - which won't even be valid by that point.

Remove that console.log statement, and `messages` won't be a dependency any more.  No more loop.  `id` and `messageArray` are actual dependencies, and should be added; neither one is *modified* in the useEffect, so no loop.

**IF** you need the `console.log('Changes: ', messages)`, don't do it in *this* useEffect - create another **JUST FOR THE CONSOLE.LOG**.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Changes: ', messages);
}, [messages]);
```

this will only be called when messages *changes*, and doesn't modify messages, so no loop.